# Prevent usage of special chars in form with jQuery validationEngine

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jQuery validation engine for the user registration form on my site and I'm looking for a way to implement an additional control to prevent the usage of special characters, only allowing the use of letters, numbers and the following characters: ,-'.
I've tried the following rule, but it won't prevent the usage of:  #;" for example.
Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong with the regex?

```
"noSpecialChars": {
    "regex": /^[0-9a-zA-Z\ \'\-\,]+$/,
    "alertText": "* Text contains invalid characters"
},
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. Tested with latest version from github and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z\'\-\,]+$/
```

this catches only sequences of chars case-insensitive, numbers and `'` `-` `,`  without spaces! If you allow spaces only add `\.` after the `Z`.
you can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/)